# Expected number of times to roll die before getting higher number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Consider the following cute problem:

I roll a fiar 10-sided die (with sides labeled 1-10) until I get a number greater than or equal to my previous roll. If the epxexted value for the number of rolls is $m/n$ with $m,n$ relatively prime positive integers, find $m+n$ modulo $1000$.

Forgive the useless stuff at the end, this problem is from a math contest similar to the AIME.

Now I heard from someone that there is a recursive solution to this but I haven't found using recursion. Instead I have an ugly solution with a silly mistake somewhere. I wish 2 things:

1. Can anyone find a nice recursion solution?
2. Please identify the mistake in my solution. I know my method works, but I must have made some mistake somewhere because I am not getting the desired answer $601$.

Here is my solution.

We approach this in the least cleverest way possible by using the standard definition of expected value.

Suppose it takes $k$ rolls before we stop rolling. If we roll $r_1,...,r_k$ in that order, we need $r_k \ge r_{1}>r_{2}>...>r_{k-1}$. We shall first count the number of instances like this, and then compute the probability by dividing by $10^k$. If $r_k>r_{k-1}$, then we can choose $r_1,...r_k$ in $\dbinom{10}{k}$ ways and they are automatically ordered. If $r_k=r_{k-1}$ we similarly have $\dbinom{10}{k-1}$. We sum the binomial coefficients to find the total number of ways, and applying Pascal's formula we have $\dbinom{11}{k}$ ways total. Thus the probability is $\dbinom{11}{k}/10^k$ and the term in the expectation is $k\dbinom{11}{k}/10^k$.

Note that $2 \le k \le 11$. The lowerbound is trivial and the upperbound is achieved by $r_1,..r_k=10,9,...1,10$. Thus the expected number of rolls is the sum of $k\dbinom{11}{k}/10^k$ from $k=2$ to $k=11$. Now, this sum is quite easy to evaluate by hand if you use the clever identity that sum from $k=0$ to $N$ of $kx^k\dbinom{N}{k}$ equals $Nx(x+1)^{N_1}$, which is obtained by taking the derivative of the binomial theorem identity. Hopefully its clear how to apply it. Using this trick, I find the expectation is

$11/(10)^{11}(11^{10}-10^{11})$

which is confirmed by wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+k%2811+choose+k%29%2F10%5Ek+from+k%3D2+to+k%3D11

Note tht the demoniator is prime to the numerator so we simply take the numerator modulo $1000$ which is easy by the Binomial Theorem (again!) and evaluates to $611$. Hence the answer to the problem is $611$.

Note that my answer is similar to the official answer of $601$. Perhaps the official answer is wrong.

Note: this is definitely not intended solution because it involves evaluating a sum using an obscure identity I derived using calculus, as well as the Binomial theorem applied twice, and pascal's identity, and its too long. i know the intended solution involves recursion.

Comment: If the answer involves recursion, the most likely prospect is the number of sides on the dice. Have you tried to solve the problem for one, two and three sided dice to see if some pattern emerges which can be used as the basis of a recursive argument?

Comment: No because I just worked through 15 problems and its 1 in the morning :). I'm sure I can find the recursion solution but I don't feel like thinking more about this problem for much longer. I want to see the "nice solution" and move on.

Comment: What does the problem mean? Until we meet or exceed the **immediately** previous roll? So is $9,1,1$  an instance where the number is $3$?

Comment: As I read it, you need $r_k \ge r_1 \gt \text{ all of } r_2, r_3, \dots r_{k-1}$, but there is no requirement that $r_2 \gt r_3$ etc. In that case, you are just asking for the expected number of rolls such that $r_k \ge r_1$ because if an intermediate one is greater that or equal to $r_1$ you quit there.

Comment: Andre: it says greater than or equal to. Ross: clearly that is not what the problem is asking. If there is no requirement on the first k rolls how do you know you haven't stopped yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1,2,3,\ldots\;$ let $A_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ roll occurs, and let $I_{A_i}$ be its indicator function. Note that the maximum number of rolls possible is $11$, for the case that the first $10$ rolls are $10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1$. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(\text{#Rolls}) &=& E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{11}{I_{A_i}}\right) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{11}{E\left(I_{A_i}\right)} \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^{11}{P\left(A_i\right)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

For the $i_{th}$ roll to occur we need rolls $1,\ldots,i-1$ to be a descending sequence of integers each taking a value between $1$ to $10$ inclusive. The number of ways for this to occur is the number of ways to choose $i-1$ of $10$ available values. This is $\binom{10}{i-1}$. The *total* number of ways for $i-1$ rolls to occur is $10^{i-1}$. Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(\text{#Rolls}) &=& \sum_{i=1}^{11}{\binom{10}{i-1} \left(\dfrac{1}{10}\right)^{i-1}} \\
&=& \left(1+\dfrac{1}{10}\right)^{10}\qquad\text{(by the Binomial Theorem)} \\
&=& \left(\dfrac{11}{10}\right)^{10} \\
&=& \dfrac{25937424601}{10000000000}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Taking *modulo* $1000$ of numerator plus denominator gives $601$.

Sorry, I don't see a recursive solution.

Comment: Fixed typo in the indexing.

Comment: I have some comments. First of all you propose a different solution using indicator functions. This is nice and it is correct. But also I would like for you to point out what is specifically wrong with my solution, because I still don't see the mistake.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaBenabou I think the problem is with "we need $r_k \ge r_{1}>r_{2}>...>r_{k-1}$". I think this should be $r_{1}>r_{2}>...>r_{k-1}\leq r_k$. Your work after that seems OK.

Comment: You are correct about the inequality. But even if it is fixed, it gives the same answer, no?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou I don't think so. E.g. you can have 6,4,2,1,4 which your answer doesn't count.

Comment: Ahhhhh correct now lets see if I can get the correct answer by fixing my solution! I'll post as an answer if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As Mick A notes, the correct condition is $r_{1}>r_{2}>...>r_{k-1} \le r_k$. What happened is I misread "previous roll" as "previous rolls" which led me to believe that $r_k \ge r_{1}>r_{2}>...>r_{k-1}$. Now we can proceed as a similar manner as my solution.

If $r_k$ is equal to any of $r_1,...,r_{k-1}$ there $k-1$ choices for which one its equal to. Then there are $\dbinom{10}{k-1}$ ways and everything is automatically ordered. So total $(k-1)\dbinom{10}{k-1}$. Else there are $k-1$ ways to choose the $i$ such that $r_i<r_k<r_{i+1}$ and then we can choose $r_1,..,r_k$ in $\dbinom{10}{k}$ ways and again everything is ordered. So the total number of ways is

$(k-1)\dbinom{10}{k-1}+(k-1)\dbinom{10}{k}=(k-1)\dbinom{11}{k}$

and the correct sum for the expected value is sum from $k=2$ to $11$ of

$k(k-1)\dbinom{11}{k}/(10^k)=11\dbinom{10}{k}(k-1)/10^{k}$ which we can evaluate in a similr way to my first solution (break up the sum and use the same technique) and does give the correct answer $601$.